# Ask the User if Switch 1 is on or off

Tags: python

How to ask the user if switch 1 is on or off? If it is on, then display the message "The light is on"; if it is off then display the message "The light is off"

Also, how do I do the same thing but with two switches, for example
if the two switches are on; "The light is on" and so on.

[image]

Comment: There are multiple ways of asking user a question, for example You can call him. However, if You want us to help You with some code, You should post Your efforts first.

Comment: Have you tried to find the answers in python manual or to Google them? Or, at least, to use the search function on this site?

Comment: I've done if statements, but I can't seem to make it work,

Comment: Added my efforts, I'm a beginner so don't judge me haha

Comment: Please post code as plain text, not as an image.

Comment: Hm, downvoting does not really appear fair to me - AGAC seems to be a complete beginner and at least he added what he tried so far - even if he seems to have misunderstood how 'input' works.

Comment: @Aconcagua AGAC's original question did not have any code, and then the code was a link to picture. His/her edits made it a good question, but after people had already downvoted.

Comment: @AlbertRothman Only to justify my previous comment: The image (a beginner's fault) was already there when I found the question rated 0 (zero). Not worth to argue any further, though...

Comment: @Aconcagua, Fair point. And not disagreeing.. just explaining why it is likely people downvoted it...tbh, I think people in general are a little to trigger happy with downvotes for new users of the site in general..but I guess that's a topic for meta...

Comment: @AlbertRothman Nothing more to add...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
answer = input("Is the light on or off?")
if answer == "on":
    # handle 'on' case
elif answer == "off":
    # handle 'off' case
else
    # handle error
```

You'll find some more information e. g. [here](http://www.python-course.eu/input.php) (or google for 'python input').

A little more advanced: convert answer to upper case and compare against "ON", "OFF", then you are case insensitive (so a user can answer on, On, ON, oN – OK, the last one is odd...).

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AGAC You're welcome - would be nice if you accepted an answer, though. Choose Albert's or mine, whichever you like better...

Answer (score 0):

Give the input a variable and then check against that. Input returns the user's input not  a boolean, so what you want to do is check the input against a string("on" or "off"). for example

```
power=input("is the light on or off")
if power=="on":
```

Then go from there. Here's some documentation for i/o. http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html
finally, people on SO prefer if you use code blocks in you questions rather than link images.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Solved it now,

Comment: If you like my answer or the one above you should accept one of them using the check mark button. Additionally, if you haven't already, I recommend taking the site tour. It explains best practices, and should shed some light on why your question got downvotes and negative response in the comments.http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score -1):

def Light():
while True:
#ask for user input
choice1 = str(input("is the light on or off?: "))
#check if switch is on
if choice1.lower() == "on":
print("the light is on ") #on output to screen
break
#check else if switch is  off
elif choice1.lower() == "off":
print("the light is off") #off output to screen
break
Light()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).